# Al volver de la funcion ajax no me reconoce los valores que tenia pasados por get

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo una funcion ajax normalita, para probar que funcion y en un archivo vacio funciona bien pero en el archivo en el que tengo valores pasados por get, no me funciona ya que al ejecutar la funcion me dice que **UNDEFINED INDEX: 'nombre_indice'**, porque puede ser?? la función en si funciona bien pero al regresar falla.

```
$('#enviar').submit(function() {

    var poligono = $('#poligono').val();
    var comunidad = $('#comunidad').val();

    var datasend = 'poligono=' + poligono + '&comunidad=' + comunidad;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: './tarjetas/finc.php',
        data: datasend,
        success: function(res) {
        $('#zonaF').html(res);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Haz 2 cosas, 1º Console log al "res" para comprobar lo que te devuelve. 2º asegúrate que zonaF se le puede añadir contenido aunque sea de forma manual para comprobar que todo funcionará bien en un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo quitando los parámetros que le pasaba por get y ahora los paso metidos en **$_SESSIONS** ahora funciona perfectamente muchas gracias.